# Максимальное число среди нескольких списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список:

```
spisok = [[1001,100,0,0],[1312,101,0,0],[1111,200,0,0]]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы взялось максимальное число с индексом 1 среди списков
и вывелось число с индексом 0 у списка, в котором находится максимальное число?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе вашу попытку решения?

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: IMO если вы привыкните получать  ответы, не прилагая даже минимальных усилий на самостоятельный поиск ответа,  это принесет вам скорее вред чем пользу

Comment: Ответ кроется в правильном использовании параметра `key` функции `max(iterable, key)` ;)

Comment: это мне нечего не дает

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?pws=0&gl=us&q=python+max+~%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5&oq=python+max+~%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BE+%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Исходный код**:

---

```py
#Переменная listOfNumbers — хранит в себе ссылку на список [[1001,100,0,0], [1312,101,0,0], [1111,200,0,0]].
listOfNumbers = [[1001,100,0,0], [1312,101,0,0], [1111,200,0,0]]

#Вывод списка, в котором находится максимальное число под целочисленным индексом 1.
print([c for c in listOfNumbers if max([c[1] for c in listOfNumbers]) in c][0][0])
```

---

Ход выполнения программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Генераторы списков

Воспользуемся *генераторами списков*. **Генератор списков** — способ создания нового списка применяя к каждому элементу последовательности определённое выражение.

---

```py
>>> [number * 2 for number in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

---

Если же ссылка на список хранится в переменной.

---

```py
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [number * 2 for number in numbers]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

---

```py
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [number for number in numbers if number == 3]
[3]
```

---

В этом случае, Python будет добавлять те элементы родительского списка numbers в новый список, **которые равняются трём**.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И выведет у вас 1111:)

Comment: а можно объяснить что там происходит?

Comment: Естественно, буквально через несколько минут.

Comment: У вас ошибка небольшая. Вместо `c[1]` надо писать `c[0]`, если я правильно задачу понял)

Comment: нет все правильно вывело 1111

Comment: @СашаРоманов "максимальное число(с индексом 1)" если вы под этим подразумеваете, что надо найти максимум во втором столбце, то да, значит я неправильно понял задание

Comment: Подробное объяснение кода программы я попытаюсь отправить через два часа. Я оповещу вас.

Answer (score 6):

Проще и эффективнее всего воспользоваться встроенной функцией [max(iterable, key)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
records = [[1001,100,0,0],[1312,101,0,0],[1111,200,0,0]]
res = max(records, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

---

```
print(res)
> 1111
```

---

пошагово:

```
In [49]: max(records, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[49]: [1111, 200, 0, 0]

In [50]: max(records, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
Out[50]: 1111
```