# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Я пытаюсь ввести два любых числа через пробел, добавить к каждому единицу и вывести их:

```
nk = input().split
for n, k in nk:
    n, k = n + 1, k + 1
    print(n)
    print(k)
```

Я пыталась сделать так:

```
nk = input().split
nk_list = list(map(int, nk))
n = nk_list[0] + 1
k = nk_list[1] + 1
print(n)
print(k)
```

Но выдается одна и та же ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/admin1/PycharmProjects/2.py", line 64, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: input().split  —>  input().split()

Answer (score 2):

`print('{0} {1}'.format(*[i + 1 for i in map(int, input().split())]))`

Answer (score -1):

### **Строковый метод** split()

*Методы* — это функции, привязанные к какому-либо объекту.

Метод split() является строковым методом. *Строковый метод split()* — разбивает строку по указанному в качестве параметра метода разделителю, где разделителем строки по умолчанию является пробел.

---

```py
>>> sentence = input()   
Поздравляю всех с праздником!
>>> sentence.split()
['Поздравляю', 'всех', 'с', 'праздником!']
```

---

В результате получится список из четырёх элементов.

### **Добавление единицы и вывод чисел на экран**

Воспользуемся [генератором списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1080002/369173).

---

```py
[print(int(c) + 1) for c in input('Введите числа: ').split()]
```

---